# Share point list view custmization in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, publishing-site

I am trying to create a publishing site on Share point 2013. I have a custom list which contain a schedule about a walk-in clinic hours. It show like a table though I can change the view to calendar view or table view etc. But I want to give a custom view for the user. something like:

Title Events on september 9,213
Address 343 some street in some country
Open-time: 8:00am
Close-time: 3:00 pm

I am very new with web parts and with share point. Please help! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to create web part and add that web part to the site and have all the styling in to the web part. There is link which describe how to create visual web part for SharePoint 2013 and how to deploy it all stuff like. http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/visual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score -1):

You can customize your list view using browser or using SharePoint Designer. Please refer the below detailed technet article on customizing list views:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx

Comment: Thanks, But I tried to customize the list view in all way but Couldn't  found the right view the suits my needs. But I found the solution for this as created a visual web part for doing the styling stuff.I found a solution to create web part and add that web part to the site and have all the styling in to the web part. There is link which describe how to create visual web part for SharePoint 2013 and how to deploy it all stuff like. http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/visual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html[^]